# Ruby sort_by help unpredictable object attribute

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array with 2 different types of objects.  They all have similar properties, like ratings / title etc...

An example is:

`array = array.sort_by { |o| [o.type1.rating] }`

Sometimes the array has 2 object types type1 and type2 is there any way to sort both of them using the sort_by method?

Answer (score 1):

you can use some metaprogramming for this:

```
array = array.sort_by { |o| o.respond_to?(:type1) ? [o.type1.rating] : [o.type2.rating] }
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write something like this

```
array.sort_by{ |arr| [arr.type1.present? ? arr.type1.rating : arr.type2.rating] }
```